# OverGrive not launching after install [previous board answers not solving issue]

Tags: google-drive

New Linux user here [go easy if you can...]

I downloaded the .deb from: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive (version 3.1.3 beta). However, when I try to launch overGrive from the dash, the window never pops up. I just get the spinning wheel for ~6sec and then nothing.

I have tried to remove (i.e. `sudo apt-get remove overgrive`) and reinstall by double-clicking the deb package and running dpkg from the command line. It seems to install fine both ways, but I can never get the window to launch.  I am on a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After checking various boards; a solution that worked was to install google's api-python client from the command line using the following commands (several times):

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip

sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

However, this did not solve the issue.  The terminal outputs for the two above commands were as follows, respectively:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (10.0.1)
```

And

```
Requirement already up-to-date: google-api-python-client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.7.3)
```

Does anyone have any idea how might be able to solve this issue?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: After much ado... I realized that something in my gnome extensions was not allowing the sync icon to appear in the toolbar on Ubuntu 18.04. If you're having troubles thinking it's not running, it could be a gnome extension not allowing the overgrive icon to appear and cutting off your access. Try turning off all extensions using the Gnome Tweak Tool and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install --user --upgrade oauth2client
```

Wim